# Smart remote repositories on Artifactory OSS

Tags: artifactory

I am trying to set up some Maven smart remote repositories on an Artifactory OSS instance (version is 5.4.5).
I am following the guide at https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Smart+Remote+Repositories and configuring the remote repository as follows:

- Package type: *Maven*
- Repository key: *foo-repo*
- URL: *http://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/api/foo-repo*

All I get when I input that and click on "Test" to test the connection is a message telling me that there was a 404.

If I test the same values on an Artifactory Pro instance (also version 5.4.5), I get the expected "Artifact Remote Repository Detected" dialog, as described in the documentation.

So can anyone confirm that smart remote repositories are a "Pro" only feature? The tutorial page at https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Smart+Remote+Repositories doesn't make this clear at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the "Smart Remote Repository" is a PRO version feature.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, do you think this could be explicitly written in the official documentation?

Comment: I've FW your request to the Product and Technical writers teams. Now it's in their hands :)